# Not able to alert or store serializeArray

Tags: jquery, json

I made a code in which i am getting the name and the value of selected checkbox and serializeArray it into a form of array . I was able to do this via some help i found in stack but i am stuck at a point where i am not able to store that array inside a new variable or alert it . The only thing it does is that its being visible on console if return it into console . I have removed the line `var eg = JSON.stringify(obj)` which i wanted to store the final result in from the below code . But as i said its not working .

```
var data = $('input[type=checkbox]').serializeArray(),obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   obj[data[i].name] = obj[data[i].name] || [];
   obj[data[i].name].push(data[i].value);
}    
// your JSON string
return console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Also my output is like

```
{"territories[nl]":["1"],"territories[px]":["1"],"territories[tu]":["1"]}
```

but i wanted the result to be like

```
{"territories[nl]":"1","territories[px]":"1","territories[tu]":"1"}
```

Like the value not in like `["1"]` but `"1"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var data = $('input[type=checkbox]').serializeArray(),obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   obj[data[i].name] = data[i].value || "";
}    
// your JSON string
return console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: how to store this into any variables so that i can use that to be passed through ajax ? as i tried storing it into a variable it didnt worked ?

Comment: There was some problem with my chrome due to which it was not able to alert the value . I tried with some other browser and it worked thanks for your help :)